# Replace char conditionally based on preceding char

Tags: java

For an assignment, I have to read a file containing a movie script and write some methods that will convert certain chars to another char given other parameters. For example, I am trying to search through lines and convert any 'r' into a 'h' if the 'r' follows a vowel (a,e,i,o,u). I am looking for basic java syntax. Here is what I have for the main where I read the text and then :

```
package jaws.accent;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JawsAccent {

    public static char convert(Scanner in ) {
        String word = in .nextLine();
        char r = 'r';
        if ((word.contains("a") || word.contains("a") || word.contains("a") || word.contains("a") || word.contains("u"))) {
            r.replace(r, 'h');
        }
        return r;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
        File jaws = new File("JawsScript.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(jaws);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "convert any 'r' into a 'h' if the 'r' follows a vowel (a,e,i,o,u)" - [Regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) will solve your problem.  Or you can just call `String#replace` with `ar`, `er`, `ir`, `or`, and `ur`.

Comment: Calling the method you've written would probably be a good start, and then read the error message, understand it and try to figure out how you can change that line to make it do what you want, and then print out the value your function returns, to see what you should change to fix it. And then you will probably have working code (not ideal working code, but one step at a time).

Comment: I don't think I'm really even close to getting the right solution though. Plus, this doesn't even compile.

Comment: Question: are you allowed to use regular expressions? has the teacher placed any such restrictions upon your code?

Comment: @Patrick there are no restrictions that I know of.

Comment: @MattShade OK, I added a RegEx version to my answser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this. I am assuming that the teacher intends for you to step through the data one character at a time while generating output. You will thus be able to check whether or not the preceding was a vowel by maintaining a boolean or by inspecting prior index. Here I show a simple for loop that allows you to step through each char of a string (let us assume the string doesn't contain non-BMP codepoints):

```
public class SampleJava {
    public static String transformation(String line) {
        StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();
        boolean afterVowel = false;
        for(char c : line.toCharArray()) {
            char out = c;
            switch(c) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                afterVowel = true;
                break;
            case 'r':
                if(afterVowel) out = 'h';
                // fall-through
            default:
                afterVowel = false;
            }
            toReturn.append(out);
        }
        return toReturn.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File jaws = new File("JawsScript.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(jaws);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            line = transformation(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**RegEx version:**

If the teacher allows you to use [regular expression patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), then the transformation code could be much shorter. However, those might be difficult for you to understand how they are written and why they work, unless you study RegEx documentation and examples for a while.

```
public static String transformation(String line) {
    return line.replaceAll("(?<=[aeiou])r", "h");
}
```

Comment: I pretty much understand what your code outputs, but I also need to place 4 other conditions so it would be best it was a method of its own. So to do that would I have to put "File jaws = new File("JawsScript.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(jaws);" for every method?

Comment: @Matt are you saying that you don’t know how to create a method and pass arguments to it? You should consult a java tutorial for such language basics.

Comment: @Matt if you want to apply several different transformation methods on each String line, then you should append to a StringBuffer and return a String— rather than outputting directly to System.out as I have shown here. You should be able to manage that on your own I hope. If not, post a new question when you have given sufficient effort and research.

Comment: No I can do that. I just need to make 5 different methods that will go into one method. These methods will perform the following: 1. If there's an 'r' following a vowel ('a', 'e', i', 'o', or 'u'), replace 'r' with 'h'. 2. If a word ends in 'a', append an 'r'. 3. Replace the word "very" with the word "wicked". 4. If 'r' is at the end of a word and is preceded by "ee" or 'i' replace 'r' with "yah" instead of 'h'. and 5. If 'r' is at the end of a word and is preceded by "oo", replace 'r' with "wah". I'm just confused with how to read text from a file in a method.

Comment: @Matt the parameter of your method should be a String, and it should return the transformed String. You don’t read need to do File input/output in the transformation method itself, nor should you.

Comment: would you mind showing me what you wrote but in a method with a return statement? I'm just trying to get an idea of how to do the rest of them. I know I'm asking pretty dumb questions but I just seem to have a lot of trouble with this file stuff. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @MattShade I said "post a new question when you have given sufficient effort and research." However, even though that advice was ignored, I went ahead and edited my answer to fit all your requirements. Do not alter your question further please.

Answer (score -1):

```
String result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("a.txt")).stream()
            .map(l -> l.replaceAll("ar","ah"))
            .map(l -> l.replaceAll("er","eh"))
            .map(l -> l.replaceAll("ir","ih"))
            .map(l -> l.replaceAll("or","oh"))
            .map(l -> l.replaceAll("ur","uh"))
            .reduce((e,o) -> e.concat("\n").concat(o))
            .get();

    System.out.println(result);
```

Simple and readable code.